# Rendering Array List in HTML Dropdown from Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, google-apps-script, client-side

I am trying to get a list from my spreadsheet into the html select drop-down in the web application. I was able to pass a reference number into the html, but not the list from spreadsheet. I have gone through the code multiple time but can't seem to find what i am doing wrong. I hope someone is able to put me through on this

HTML

```
<!--language: lang-html -->

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="paymentForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
            <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">LADIES LUXURY 1</p>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-2"> <!-- STRAP/BAND -->
              <label for="strapband" class="form-label">STRAP/BAND</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="strapband" name="strapband" required>
              <option selected disabled value="">Choose..</option>
              <?= list; ?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">BUY NOW</button>
        </form>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
  
  <?!= include('Updates'); ?>
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://js.paystack.co/v1/inline.js"></script>
</body>
```

DOGET & LOAD FUNCTION

```
const APP_NAME = "CATEGORY SALES"
const LAD_NAME = "LADIES CATEGORY SALES"
const MEN_NAME = "MEN CATEGORY SALES"
const COU_NAME = "COUPLE CATEGORY SALES"
const REP_NAME = "WATCH REPAIR"
const GIF_NAME = "GIFTING SERVICE"
var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CK1bAcrTAOabkzK0YxliVFFh8VFPYIYXDy6ocvnGuGY/edit#gid=1312844985";
const uuid = Utilities.getUuid()
var Route = {};
Route.path = function(route,callback){
  Route[route] = callback;
}

function doGet(e) {

  Route.path("ll1",loadSalesFormLL1);
  Route.path("ll2",loadSalesFormLL2);
  Route.path("ll3",loadSalesFormLL3);

  if (Route[e.parameters.v]) {
    return Route[e.parameters.v]();
  }else {
    return render ("404");
  }
}


function loadSalesFormLL1() {   
var referenceNumber = uuid;   
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);   
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("DROPDOWNS");   
var list = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();   //Logger.log(list);   
var htmlListArray = list.map(function(r){ return '<options>' + r[0] + '</options>' ; }).join('');   Logger.log(htmlListArray);   
return render("LL1",{list: htmlListArray, referenceNumber}).setTitle(LAD_NAME).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL); }
```

RENDER FUNCTION

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}


function render (file,argsObject){

var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
if(argsObject){
var keys = Object.keys(argsObject);

keys.forEach(function(key){
tmp\[key\] = argsObject\[key\];
});
}//END IF
return tmp.evaluate();
}
```

Comment: Can you verify that your request is going through (reaching your spreadsheet)? You can see that in the Network tab of your browser. If the request is going through, and reaching your spreadsheet, what is the response (the info you should be getting back)?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (include the doGet function and a complete html)

Comment: LAD_NAME is undefined

Comment: I have just added the reproducible example.

and the LAD_NAME has been defined above in the script and it worked

Comment: The suggested page answer looks like there are some javascript on the client side, i just need a clean job that will output the array on the dropdown using " <?= list; ?> ". I believe this is the safest method